# XCode working with TFS 2013 via Eclipse

Tags: ios, eclipse, xcode, tfs, ignore

I develop iOS app my company decide to use TFS server, BUT we face many problems to make it works with xcode the best solution "As my research finalize" is use it via eclipse as the other BB, android and windows phone works.

Instruction found in this [link](http://www.satinderrana.com/blog/2013/06/xcode-and-tfs-integration-in-8-simple-steps/).

BUT my own problem is eclipse alway ignore .pch -IDK if other file got ignored to- file that result in build failed where my teammate pull the project.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: We are also Fetching same problem. Have you found any solutions?